# How to expland the Wordpress menu zone?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have the following problem: when I try to add more options to the menu it becomes distorted.

This is how I want it to look like:

Normal menu

[image]

But this is how it looks after I add some more options:

Distorted menu

[image]

Logo is small and it shouldn't take half of the menu bar.

Could anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Thank you

Comment: post some code or share your site link

Comment: www.unifycrowdfunding.com

Answer (score 0):

I saw your site, you need to disable/remove the `max-width` for `.home #header #menu-header`. see image for reference:

[image]

Hope this may help you.

Comment: This did help, it now shows everything how I needed to! Thank you very much for your help!